# Android Camera saving image, but not sure where it is being saved

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera, mediastore

I am stuck in a bit of a problem, my android studio application has a custom camera interface, it is able to save its images by calling the

```
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),bitmap, "photo@"+System.currentTimeMillis() , "some photo okay");
```

However, when i start the app, I can view it in the files section of the emulator. However I am not exactly sure where it is saved, since I will need to access it and use it later.

How can i view all the files that I have saved using the InsertImage method, that is how do I programmatically list all the files that have been saved using this method.

Thank you.

**My Code**

```
 private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {


        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),bitmap, "photo@"+System.currentTimeMillis() , "some photo okay");
        camera.startPreview();

    }
```

Please note I am using the old (deprecated) Camera API

Comment: If you can see it with the Files app (is that what you mean with files section?) the app will tell you full path too. Well mostly. Further: insertImage() is deprecated too.